# Jquery - continue with form submit after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
kreiraj_korisnika.on('submit', function(){
    if(error_count != false) {
        kreiraj_korisnika.submit();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I continue with form submitting when **error_count** is **true** (without AJAX submit)?

Comment: What if you don't run any code in that case? If you don't prevent it, it will submit as normal.

Comment: Tried that, nothing is happening.

Comment: If you don't do anything the form will submit normally, as in don't call `kreiraj_korisnika.submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `preventDefault()` method of event variable to avoid the submit. Try sopmething like:

```
kreiraj_korisnika.on('submit', function(e) {
   if (error_count)
   {
      // avoid the submit...
      e.preventDefault();

      // show your erros messages
   }       
});
```

If error_count`variable` is `true`, the submit will happen.

Comment: I must have done something wrong o.O. This is working :). Thank you for your help :)

Comment: In jQuery, `return false` should include `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @pimvdb I have read article about **return_false** and **e.preventDefault()**, and according to article it is better to use **return_false** because that way you are preventing DOM bubble up. [http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/](Article)

Answer (score 0):

Is kreiraj_korisnika actually an jQuery object ?
If you just assigned it to a result of getElementById() it won't work.

In that case:

```
$(kreiraj_korisnika).on('submit', function(e){
var errorCount = 0;

if(errorCount == 0)
{
    this.submit();
}
else
{
alert('Invalid form input !');
e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Léon